# Symfony FOSRestController

Tags: mysql, rest, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have API for project and I create function for find Project by skill and when I find Project by skill = Java Query Builder give me result projects with "Java script", "Java ME" and all skill who have part word "Java".

How to make a hundred percent match?

This is my Controller and action:

```
 /**
 * Get Project for parameter,<br />
 *    
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 * resource = true,
 * description = "Get projects by parameters",
 * output = "Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Project",
 * statusCodes = {
 *      200 = "Returned when successful",
 *      404 = "Returned when the Dream is not found"
 * },
 * section="All Projects"
 * )
 *
 *
 * RestView()
 *
 * @QueryParam(name="status", strict=true, requirements="[a-z]+", description="status of project", nullable=true)
 * @QueryParam(name="skill", strict=true, requirements="^[a-zA-Z ^0-9().,+]+", description="skill of project", nullable=true)
 * @QueryParam(name="close", requirements="\d+", description="project by close")
 * @QueryParam(name="main_skill", strict=true, requirements="^[a-zA-Z ^0-9().,+]+", description="project by main_skill", nullable=true)
 * @QueryParam(name="count", requirements="\d+", default="10", description="Count project at one page")
 * @QueryParam(name="page", requirements="\d+", default="1", description="Number of page to be shown")
 * @QueryParam(name="sort_by", strict=true, requirements="^[a-zA-Z]+", default="created", description="Sort by", nullable=true)
 * @QueryParam(name="sort_order", strict=true, requirements="^[a-zA-Z]+", default="DESC", description="Sort order", nullable=true)
 *
 * @param  ParamFetcher $paramFetcher
 * @return View
 *
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException when not exist
 */
public function getProjectsAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
{
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $repository = $manager->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Project');


    if (!$paramFetcher->get('status') && !$paramFetcher->get('main_skill') && !$paramFetcher->get('close') && !$paramFetcher->get('skill')) {
        $queryBuilder = $manager->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Project')->findAllProject($paramFetcher);
    }

    if($paramFetcher->get('main_skill'))
    {
        $queryBuilder = $manager->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Project')->findForMainSkillProject($paramFetcher);
    }

    if($paramFetcher->get('close'))
    {
        $queryBuilder = $manager->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Project')->findForCloseProject($paramFetcher);
    }


    if($paramFetcher->get('status'))
    {
        $queryBuilder = $manager->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Project')->findForStatusProject($paramFetcher);
    }

    if ($paramFetcher->get('skill')) {

        $queryBuilder = $manager->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Project')->findForSkillProject($paramFetcher);
    }

    $projectAll = $queryBuilder[1];
    $paginator = $this->get('paginator');

    $pagination = $paginator->getPaginated(
        $paramFetcher->get('count'),
        $paramFetcher->get('page'),
        $paramFetcher->get('sort_by'),
        $paramFetcher->get('sort_order'),
        $projectAll
    );

    $projectResponse = new ProjectResponse();
    $projectResponse->setProjects($queryBuilder[0]);
    $projectResponse->setCount($pagination->getCount());

    return $projectResponse;
}
```

and this function `findForMainSkillProject` and `findForSkillProject`:

```
 public function findForMainSkillProject($paramFetcher)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('d');
    $qb
        ->select('d')
        ->from('ArtelProfileBundle:Project', 'd')

        ->where('d.currentStatus != :identifier1', 'd.main_skill = :identifier')
        ->setParameter('identifier1', 'not_approved')
        ->setParameter('identifier', $paramFetcher->get('main_skill'));
    $count_by_skill = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    $qb
        ->orderBy('d.'.$paramFetcher->get('sort_by'), $paramFetcher->get('sort_order'))
        ->setFirstResult($paramFetcher->get('count') * ($paramFetcher->get('page') - 1))
        ->setMaxResults($paramFetcher->get('count'))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();

    return [$results, $count_by_skill];
}

public function findForSkillProject($paramFetcher)
{
    $close = $paramFetcher->get('close');

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->from('ArtelProfileBundle:Project','d')
        ->select('d as projects')
        ->where('d.currentStatus != :identifier1')
        ->setParameter('identifier1', 'not_approved');

    if (!empty($close)) {
        $qb
            ->where('d.close = :identifier')
            ->setParameter('identifier', $paramFetcher->get('close'));
    }

    $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('d.skills', $qb->expr()->literal('%' . $paramFetcher->get('skill') . '%')));
    $count_by_skill = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    $qb
        ->orderBy('d.'.$paramFetcher->get('sort_by'), $paramFetcher->get('sort_order'))
        ->setFirstResult($paramFetcher->get('count') * ($paramFetcher->get('page') - 1))
        ->setMaxResults($paramFetcher->get('count'))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();
    $build_result = [];
    foreach($results as $result){
        $build_result[] = $result['projects'];
    }

    return [$build_result, $count_by_skill];
}
```

**UPDATE**
I merge two Query Builder in one by skill or main_skill but when I use '%'.$paramFetcher->get('skill').'%' I have "Java ME" or "Java Script" in skills if I use $paramFetcher->get('skill') I QB find project by mainskill and not find by skill
How to make a hundred percent match?

```
  public function findForSkillProject($paramFetcher)
{
    $close = $paramFetcher->get('close');

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->from('ArtelProfileBundle:Project','d')
        ->select('d as projects')
        ->where('d.currentStatus != :identifier1')
        ->setParameter('identifier1', 'not_approved');

    if (!empty($close)) {
        $qb
            ->where('d.close = :identifier')
            ->setParameter('identifier', $paramFetcher->get('close'));
    }

     $qb->andWhere('d.skills LIKE :skills OR d.main_skill LIKE :skills')
        ->setParameter('skills', '%'.$paramFetcher->get('skill').'%');

    $count_by_skill = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    $qb
        ->orderBy('d.'.$paramFetcher->get('sort_by'), $paramFetcher->get('sort_order'))
        ->setFirstResult($paramFetcher->get('count') * ($paramFetcher->get('page') - 1))
        ->setMaxResults($paramFetcher->get('count'))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();
    $build_result = [];
    foreach($results as $result){
        $build_result[] = $result['projects'];
    }

    return [$build_result, $count_by_skill];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from your code:
this is looking for LIKE (e.g. 'Java' returns 'Java ME'

```
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('d.skills', $qb->expr()->literal('%' . $paramFetcher->get('skill') . '%')));
```

and this part of your code is making sure it's fully equal:

```
    ->where('d.currentStatus != :identifier1', 'd.main_skill = :identifier')
    ->setParameter('identifier1', 'not_approved')
    ->setParameter('identifier', $paramFetcher->get('main_skill'));
```

I am sure you'll be able to do the rest on your own.

Comment: I update question:
I merge two Query Builder in one by skill or main_skill but when I use '%'.$paramFetcher->get('skill').'%' I have "Java ME" or "Java Script" in skills if I use $paramFetcher->get('skill') I QB find project by mainskill and not find by skill

Comment: sorry, don't get your question

Comment: How to make a hundred percent match?